# Several labels for big figure with included subplots

Tags: labels, plot

I made a figure with matplotlib that has three subfigures in the same .pdf file, similar to this one:  [Matplotlib gallery example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot_demo.html). I included the labels "a)", "b)", "c)" **in** the image.

To reference the whole image as well as the three image parts individually, I would like to have four labels. This is the behaviour that I already have for different figures that I compose with the subcaption-package (\subfigure command).

However, the only thing that I can create so far is a single label for the whole figure.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot_with_subplots.pdf}
\caption{This plot has three parts.}
\label{fig:plot}
\end{figure}
```

Calling "figure \ref{fig:plot}" will result in things like "figure 1". However, I want an additional label like "figure \ref{fig:plot:left_plot}" that translates to "figure 1a".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The clean solution is to split the multi-plot into single plots and include them separately as sub-figures (using e.g. the `subfigure` package) that then can be labeled and referenced separately.

If you don't want to/can't do that, you can simulate the subfigures as follows. The `\phantomlabel` command works like the `\label` command, but has an additional first argument that gives the suffix to be appended to the number of the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\phantomlabel[2]%
  {\@bsphack
   \protected@write\@auxout{}%
     {\string\newlabel{#2}{{\@currentlabel#1}{\thepage}}}%
   \@esphack
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Figure~\ref{fig:plot} consists of sub-figure~\ref{fig:plot:left_plot},
sub-figure~\ref{fig:plot:right_plot}, and
sub-figure~\ref{fig:plot:somewhere else}.
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This plot has three parts.}\label{fig:plot}
  \phantomlabel{a}{fig:plot:left_plot}
  \phantomlabel{b}{fig:plot:right_plot}
  \phantomlabel{c}{fig:plot:somewhere else}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your solution gives the compiling error `Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.` which leads me to think that it doesn't work with the **hyperlink**-package activated. Sorry for not giving a MWE, I wasn't aware if hacking is required. However, I found another workaround (I think). I added some subfigures with width 0pt so they won't take any space at all. I gave them labels and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Yes. It cannot work with `\usepackage{hyperref}`.