# How to refer to non-existing subfigure?

Tags: hyperref, subfloats, subcaption, matplotlib

I ploted a big figure with several subfigures in it using **matplotlib**, because the library provides many features that are difficult to implement in tex (like shared label and shared axis). However, I would like to `\ref` these subfigures just like `subcaption` in tex. Is there any methods can do the trick?

My requirement is nearly the same as the question in [Several labels for big figure with included subplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335879/several-labels-for-big-figure-with-included-subplots).

However, the solution does not work when `hyperref` is imported. Since the answer is posted 3 years ago and it seems that it would not get any updates, I asked the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\phantomlabel}[2]{
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{
        \string\newlabel{#2}{
            {\@currentlabel#1}{\thepage}
            {\@currentlabel#1}{#2}{}
        }
    }
    \hypertarget{#2}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Figure~\ref{fig:a} consists of sub-figure~\ref{fig:a:left_plot},
sub-figure~\ref{fig:a:right_plot}, and
sub-figure~\ref{fig:a:somewhere else}.
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This plot has three parts.}\label{fig:a}
  \phantomlabel{a}{fig:a:left_plot}
  \phantomlabel{b}{fig:a:right_plot}
  \phantomlabel{c}{fig:a:somewhere else}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{fig:b} consists of sub-figure~\ref{fig:b:left_plot},
sub-figure~\ref{fig:b:right_plot}, and
sub-figure~\ref{fig:b:somewhere else}.
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{This plot has three parts.}\label{fig:b}
  \phantomlabel{a}{fig:b:left_plot}
  \phantomlabel{b}{fig:b:right_plot}
  \phantomlabel{c}{fig:b:somewhere else}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The code is modified from the answer posted by @gernot in the question I linked.
The basic idea is to create a hyper-target in the corresponding phantom label position without writing text.